# Best practice for retrieving data from the blockchain when data is hashed

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I read a very good article on "Programming Smart Contracts on Ethereum" in the Jan/Feb 2023 issue of Code magazine.

The author uses Solidity to create a contract to read/write a string containing sensitive data.  He first base64 encodes a JSON string and then passes it to the contract which is converted to a hash (to reduce gas fees) and written to the blockchain.

However, the only method in the contract is to verify that the proof exists by looking for the hash. This means you have to know ahead of time the data that was stored, encode it, and then search for the proof based on that hash.

But if you don't know what data you need, you can't create a hash.  e.g. Retrieving all customer payment transactions

The approach I see to this is storing the block number to a local database.  Then fetch the data using the block number.

example db table:

```
tblTransactions
-customerID(int)
-blockNumber(string)
```

My questions are:

1. Can you retrieve data using a block number?
2. Is this the best approach?

Comment: If you're only storing the hash, you can't get the data back out. You can use the hash to prove you *know* the data, but you can't *get* the data if you don't have it. I don't see a benefit to using the blockchain for this approach at all. I'd suggest perusing the NIST's "should I use a blockchain?" flowchart: https://twitter.com/justincormack/status/1048875246437195778

Comment: Nice chart!   In the article, the author's use case is using blockchain to combat job applicants that use fake education credentials.  The idea is that the college writes the person's credentials to the blockchain and the employer can verify them.   I don't see how that can work if you can't search by name.   Good article nonetheless.

Comment: That would fall in the "no, because PII" section, in my opinion.